# Trying to open a link from my expo app using react-native Linking

Tags: react-native, expo, deep-linking

I am trying to open google from using react-native Linking.openUrl in my app.
what happens is, it opens the browser but right after opening the browser it closes the browser and my app.

**my code**

```
    const url = "https://www.google.com";
    try {
      const canOpen = await Linking.canOpenURL(url);
      console.log(canOpen); // it returns true
      if (canOpen) {
        Linking.openURL(url);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("the error is ", error);
    }
```

I tried with other urls as well and the same happens. Can open is true, It opens a browser but right after opening the browser, it closes the browser and my app.

I did search online but could not find any potential solution.

Comment: Hi I tried with your code & it's working. Are you getting any error?

Comment: I get no, errors nothing. opens Chrome and then crashes and closes the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing different cases and solutions. I found out that, there was an issue with the emulator I was using. When I used it with an actual device It was working fine.

Thanks for your comments and answer

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try this and see if there is any error occured:

```
import { Linking } from 'react-native';

const url = "https://www.google.com";

Linking.openURL(url)
.catch(err => console.error('Error opening URL:', err));
```

Comment: I get no, errors nothing. opens Chrome and then crashes and closes the app.